# fabric.js not exporting in SVG

Tags: canvas, svg, fabricjs

I'm trying to save my canvas in SVG (included are Text and SVG).

I did a console.log(canvas) and all the objects are there. Tried to export only the text and then only the svg and still not working.

Console show:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
```

Created with Fabric.js 1.4.0

```
// Obtain a canvas drawing surface from fabric.js
        var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
        canvas.setHeight(500);
        canvas.setWidth(800);

        canvas.on('object:selected', function(e){
            console.log("sdfsdf");
        })

        // Create a text object.
        // Does not display it-the canvas doesn't
        // know about it yet.
        var hi = new fabric.Text('random text', {
            fontFamily: "agero",
            left: canvas.getWidth() / 2,
            top: canvas.getHeight() / 2     
        });

        var hi2 = new fabric.Text('helo', {
            fontFamily: "error404",
            left: 0,
            top: 0     
        });

        // Attach it to the canvas object


        setTimeout(function() {
           canvas.add(hi);
           canvas.add(hi2);
        }, 500);


        fabric.loadSVGFromURL('svg/1000.svg', function(objects, options) {
            var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);


            // ...any code for special handling of the loaded object


            // put object on the canvas
            canvas.add(obj);
        });



        console.log(canvas.toSVG());
```

Thank you for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Remove settimeout and add object directlly to canvas, you will get svg of your canvas with added objects
or if settimeout is required for you than move console.log statement in settimeout function(As Follow). You will get output as per your requirement.

```
setTimeout(function() {
       canvas.add(hi);
       canvas.add(hi2);
       console.log(canvas.toSVG());
    }, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a div with YOUR ID and in Javascript call this.

```
document.getElementById('YOUR ID').innerHTML=canvas.toSVG();
```